# Iterating over iPhone Addressbook causing addressbook sql db corruption

Tags: ios, sqlite, abaddressbook

My app has an NSOperation that opens the iphone addressbook, loops through the users's contacts and copies name and phone number into Core Data entities. Most of the time this works without issue but rarely it seems the address book gets corrupted and all contacts lost. I'm not doing any writing to the addressbook so not sure how this could happen. It doesn't throw a stack trace or crash the app. I only notice it after I run my app again. I see the following in the log...

CPSqliteStatementSendResults: file is encrypted or is not a database
checkResultWithStatement: file is encrypted or is not a database for SELECT UID, identifier, (SELECT value FROM ABMultiValueLabel WHERE ROWID = label), value FROM ABMultiValue WHERE record_id = ? AND property+0 = ?;

...and the addressbook is empty.

Is it possible to trash the addressbook just by reading from it or not closing out of it properly?

Comment: Does the addressbook stop working for `Contacts` app too, or is this problem only isolated to your app?

Comment: The addressbook is empty in the Contacts app after this happens. The Contacts app runs fine just has zero entries. I'm not editing the addressbook anywhere in my code, that's what has me baffled.

Comment: Did it happened on both the simulator and device?

Comment: Only seen it on the device. So far never on simulator or device in debug mode with Xcode. It's kind of hard to catch because it doesn't crash and we don't know it's happened until the next run of the app when addressbook is hosed.

Comment: Are use creating your own `NSOperationQueue` or are you using the `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`?

Comment: We're using our own NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 3):

This exact thing happened to me before.

You are accessing the same AB instance from two different threads and the Address Book is not thread safe.

You ned to use ABAddressBookCreate() to get an instance to use on every individual thread.

From the documentation: `Important: Instances of ABAddressBookRef cannot be used by multiple threads. Each thread must make its own instance.`

You can read more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH3-SW1).

I have confirmed that if you do read from multiple threads, the database will corrupt and the user wil loose all of their contacts.

Comment: We're using Erica Sadun's ABContactsHelper wrapper class to handle all the Contact fetching. It seems like it does separate ABAddressBookCreate() for all of its functions that access addressbook. I'll add some debugging to the app and see if I can detect anywhere where we're using the same addressbook instance across threads.